# How to associate a child element with a parent using SQLAlchemy Full stack dev udacity course

Tags: javascript, python, sqlalchemy

In the course you are supposed to make a form that creates 'todos' and then have a parent list as well. Everything worked fine until we were instructed to add a foreign key 'list_id' to the child so that it associates with the parent list. After that when I attempt to create a todo I get the integrity error saying that the list_id is null and goes against the constraint since it is set to nullable=false. How do I get the todos(child) table to associate to the parent(list) table so that is automatically matches the list_id to the parent's id? They are already set up to have a relationship but it is still not associating them. Below is the back end code to model the tables.

'''

[image]
'''

Back end to create the todo

'''

```
      @app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST']) 
      def create_todo():
      error = False
      body = {}

      try:
        description = request.get_json()['description']

        todo = Todo(description=description)
        db.session.add(todo)
        db.session.commit()
        body['description'] = todo.description
     except:
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_info())
     finally:
        db.session.close()
        print("i am in todo")
     if error:
        abort(400)
     else:
        return jsonify(body)
```

'''

This is the front side javascript for the create form

'''

```
    document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const desc = descInput.value;
    //descInput.value = '';
    console.log(desc);
    fetch('/todos/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'description': desc,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonResponse => {
      console.log('response', jsonResponse);
      li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerText = desc;
      document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(li);
      document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';
    })
    .catch(function() {
      document.getElementById('error').className = '';
    })
  }
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server code you have to explicitly set todo list to your newly created todo object before you save it (e.g. `todo = Todo(description=description, list_id=some_todolist.id)`), otherwise the `nullable=False` constraint will trigger. How you get the needed todolist object there depends on how you provide the "this todo should under this list" idea, e.g. provide the list id through request params, if the frontend knows about that.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I am new to this.